# Pubnub Auth Key and Auth Key Safety (Grant Token)

Tags: websocket, pubnub

I have stuck in here and couldn't find a solid solution.

I use PHP in server-side and Vanilla JS in the client side.

In server-side, I'm generating a auth token (https://www.pubnub.com/docs/general/basics/manage-access) for current logged in user's channel to make him able to read his channel messsages by the following code:

[image]

I'm also generating a new one when the key timeout so all OK with the generation.

But my problem is starts here:

I'm passing the key into the client like this:

[image]

And user is getting access to the channel. But the thing is, I'm passing this auth key to the client-side. Which is someone that get this user's auth token; can setup their own client and can read messages that sent to this user.

How can I deal with that?

And another one:

[image]

I'm publishing to a channel in PHP like this. But I'm able do to that without setting auth token. I'm sure auth token system is working because when I pass wrong auth key to the client it's giving 403 forbidden. But however, I'm able to publish to channel without auth key in here. Is this because it's server-side?

Thanks!

Googled everything...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### someone that get this user's auth token; can setup their own client and can read messages that sent to this user

This authorization strategy is the same as JWT. How will someone get this auth token? If you are using a secure connection to your server (TSL, aka https), and your PHP server is secured, then that is all you can do. This is the internet :)

Now how secure is the end user's machine? Are they susceptible to phishing or other schemes that might allow a hacker to gain access to their machine? Humans are the easiest thing to hack and you can't really do anything to secure them ;)

So as far as PubNub is concerned with security, you are doing exactly what very large companies have been doing for over 10 years with PubNub. The question is how secure is your server that a hacker can't get access to your code and data and get your PubNub secret key. In my 9+ years at PubNub, I've never known this to happen.

### granting permissions on your channel

You are granting too many permissions but it doesn't have any negative side effects.

- `read` - `subscribe` (receive messages), `fetch` (messages from history), and some presence stuff (`get/set state`, `here now`)
- `write` - `publish` (send messages)
- `get` and `set` - this is for [PubNub Objects](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/sdks/javascript/api-reference/objects) only which is different than [pub/sub](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/sdks/javascript/api-reference/publish-and-subscribe).

Again, no harm comes from granting permissions that have no effect on the resources you are granting to but it adds to the size of the auth token (just a little bit in this case).

### able do to that without setting auth token

When you do `setToken` you are setting that on the `pubnub` object that you use to invoke PubNub operations. The PubNUb SDK automatically adds the auth token as a query parameter in the request. So it is being passed automatically for you.

Open your browser console, select the *Network* tab, and look at any PubNub request/url. You will see the query parameter names `auth` and the value is your auth token.

### PubNub Secret Key give you all access

The [*secret key* gives your server the ability to grant permissions (generate an auth token) AND it gives your server all access to all things in your PubNub key set](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/general/security/access-control#server-side-operations). Don't let that secret key get compromised.

Comment: Thank you! Now I got it. I'm new to socket systems and I'm a backend developer so it's my nature to get afraid if a key get passes to the client side :) As you say that; unless my website's other parts doesn't have any security issues; it must be okay. :)


And about my last question: I was asking it for the server-side. In every part of client-side operations; yes. Without Token set it's going to the 403 forbidden as expected. But; when I make a publish on server-side(PHP), I'm able to do that without setting the Token. Maybe token is not required if secret key is set in the pubnub object?

Comment: Because you initialized PubNub with your pub/sub AND secret key, you have all access to all things. No auth token is required. Don't let that secret key get compromised. The secret key also is what gives you the ability to grant permissions, which you knew because that's what you were doing in the first place :)

Comment: I updated my answer to address the use of the secret key. If this answers everything, please consider giving it a "check" and +1 so everyone that views this knows this is the official answer.

Answer (score 0):

I want you to test your client side without using token with only subscribe key. Client side can read and write without token even though I make token for channels

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).